# Ho to add check-in time to Google Inbox card for Hotel Reservation?

Tags: email, google-schemas

I'm sending Hotel Reservation e-mails without E-mail markup, but nonetheless a Google Inbox card is visible and the reservation is added to Google Calendar automatically.

Arrival en departure dates are correct, but the time is shown as 00:00:00, not the correct check-in time.

How can I add the check-in time to the e-mail so that the correct time will be added to the card and to Google Calendar?

I tried adding e-mail markup with no result.

This is the markup I used:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LodgingReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "GTE-F508710",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "John  Doe"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
    "name": "Efteling Hotel",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "Europalaan 1",
      "addressLocality": "Kaatsheuvel",
      "postalCode": "5171KW",
      "addressCountry": "NL"
    },
    "telephone": "00310416537779"
  },
  "checkoutDate": "2015-08-02T11:00:00+02:00",
  "checkinDate": "2015-07-30T15:00:00+02:00",
  "modifiedTime": "2015-07-21T08:00:00+02:00"
}
</script>
```

Comment: were you able to achieve a correct departure time?

Comment: Unfortunately not. I'm using the correct markup, but inbox is still showing only the date and not the time. It seems like it's scraping the HTML data and not reading the markup.

Comment: If you post your markup, I can check out what's going on.

Comment: The markup is added to the initial question.

Comment: I copied and pasted your markup, which gave me a time for the the check in. However, it seems like check out never gives an exact time, it only specifies the date or "tomorrow." Here's my result in Inbox (http://i.stack.imgur.com/YA5m6.png).

Comment: When I test with google script, it works: http://i.imgur.com/pqkjvOE.png

Comment: But when I send an email from my ESP's software, it's not working: http://i.imgur.com/Qlg5oEE.png

Comment: Can you post the markup from the email that was sent from your ESP's software. I'd like to see how your software encoded/rendered it.

Comment: The markup I posted is copied from an e-mail from my ESP.

Comment: I would contact the software company to see if it's something on their end that's causing the check in time to not show.

Comment: It seems that we have to be whitelisted for the markup to show correctly. But, if that's the case, it's strange that the Inbox Cards are working already without any markup. I'm lost here.

Comment: That is strange. Are you sending from a Gmail account or your own domain? If you are sending from a Gmail account, are you sending it to yourself or another Gmail account? If you want to register to be whitelisted, you can find more info here (https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/registering-with-google).

Answer (score 0):

To add the check-in time using the [LodgingReservation](https://developers.google.com/gmail/markup/reference/hotel-reservation) markup, you would need to use the **checkinDate** property, below is an example for a check-in for today at 12PM:

```
"checkinDate": "2015-07-17T12:00:00-08:00"
```

For check-out, you will want to use the **checkoutDate** property:

```
checkoutDate": "2015-07-18T10:00:00-08:00"
```

You can also add a check-in goto action button by adding the **checkinUrl** property:

```
"checkinUrl": "http://examplehotelcheckin.com"
```

Here's a an example for you:

```html
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "LodgingReservation",
  "reservationNumber": "abc456",
  "reservationStatus": "http://schema.org/Confirmed",
  "underName": {
    "@type": "Person",
    "name": "Edwin"
  },
  "reservationFor": {
    "@type": "LodgingBusiness",
    "name": "Hilton San Francisco Union Square",
    "address": {
      "@type": "PostalAddress",
      "streetAddress": "333 O'Farrell St",
      "addressLocality": "San Francisco",
      "addressRegion": "CA",
      "postalCode": "94102",
      "addressCountry": "US"
    },
    "telephone": " 555-555-5555"
  },
  "checkoutDate": "2015-07-18T10:00:00-08:00",
  "checkinDate": "2015-07-17T12:00:00-08:00",
  "modifiedTime": "2015-05-01T08:00:00-08:00",
  "checkinUrl": "http://example.com"
}
</script>
```

You should receive the following as a result in [Inbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UyXdL.png):

[image]

I hope this information helps.